# Why does Xamarin UWP app fails Binary analyzer and Supported API checks?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp, wack

Have had this issue for a while with my Xamarin.Forms app. I am able to successfully build the UWP app package, but it always fails the WACK test with these issues:

> Binary analyzer
>
> Error Found: The binary analyzer test detected the following errors:
>
> File C:\Program Files\windowsapps[appname]r_2.1.2.0_x64__tpaj9sfh9f80r\clrjit.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
>
> Impact if not fixed: If the app doesn’t use the available Windows protections, it can increase the vulnerability of the customer's computer to malware.
>
> How to fix: Apply the required linker options - SAFESEH, DYNAMICBASE, NXCOMPAT, and APPCONTAINER - when you link the app.

and

> Supported APIs
>
> Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>
> API SystemFunction036 in advapi32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API DebugBreak in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API HeapValidate in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API LoadLibraryExW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API RtlCaptureContext in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API RtlVirtualUnwind in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API UnhandledExceptionFilter in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API VirtualAlloc in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> API VirtualProtect in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. clrjit.dll calls this API.
>
> Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.
>
> How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable.

So I've checked and it's always building in Release configuration and always with .NET Native enabled. Here is the content of my csproj:

```
      <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{F81FFB5A-CDC4-4EBB-B24E-43C2153EF76B}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>[AppName]</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>[AppName]</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>true</EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    ...
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-arm;win10-arm-aot;win10-x86;win10-x86-aot;win10-x64;win10-x64-aot</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>False</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64|arm</AppxBundlePlatforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm really not making progress with this one and am unable to publish to the store at the moment. For what it's worth Android and iOS are building and publishing fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Will

Comment: Have you unchecked `Compile with .NET Native tool chain` option in the project build setting?

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT The builds above were with .NET Native tool chain enabled, I believe this should be correct? [see article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/#uQIAbmvYoF3AtEwC.97). Compiling with this disabled gives a WACK error "Windows cannot install package [AppName] because package Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1 was provided but not used. This could be because package [AppName] does not depend on Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1. Only the packages that package [AppName] depends on can be installed".